# WiFi on both iMac 7,1 and MacBook Pro 12,1

Tags: drivers, kernel, broadcom, mac, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Desktop (64-bit) on an external hard disk.
I want to be able to use (plug and boot) this disk as a "Linux PC" on various hardware.

It boots fine both on my old iMac 7,1 and my MacBook Pro 12,1, but I have some WiFi problems.

In order to make the WiFi work on my iMac, I need to have `bcmwl-kernel-source` installed. But this way the WiFi won't work when I boot on the MacBook Pro.

In order to make the WiFi work on the MacBook Pro, I have to copy the firmware file `brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin` to `/lib/firmware/brcm` and delete the `bcmwl-kernel-source`. If I don't delete the `bcmwl-kernel-source` this solution won't work. But if I delete the `bcmwl-kernel-source` the WiFi won't work on the iMac.

Is there any way to make the WiFi function on both machines?

Comment: This is possible, but needs some testing. `bcmwl-kernel-source` blacklists `brcmfmac` module. You can remove it from blacklist and check. If that doesn't work well, you can write a script that will switch that setting.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the `brcmfmac` from the blacklist did the trick! Now WiFi works fine on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the WiFi to work both on the iMac 7,1 and the MacBook Pro 12,1:

1. Copy the firmware file `brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin` to `/lib/firmware/brcm`.
2. Open the terminal and enter:

   `$ cd /etc/modprobe.d`

   `$ sudo -H gedit blacklist-bcm43.conf`
3. Remove the `brcmfmac` module from the blacklist by entering a `#` before it:

   `# blacklist brcmfmac`
4. Save changes and reboot.